# in-memory SQL database system

Tags: mysql, database-recommendation, memory, in-memory-database

In an application, I am using `mysql`'s `TEMPORARY TABLE`. Since this application does not need permanent tables, I wonder if I can find an alternative RDMS designed for memory tables. I hope to find an in-memory database system, which is

1. Lightweight
2. Faster than mysql temporary table
3. Having an API for C (my programming language)

and no special features is needed, just creating table and performing SQL queries. `FK` or other advanced features are not needed.

Comment: I cannot find anything about the price in your requirement so maybe [Oracle Times Ten](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/timesten/overview/timesten-imdb-086887.html) is a possible option for you

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_in-memory_databases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options

## OPTION #1 : Create a RAM Disk

```
RAMDISK_SIZE=32g
service mysql stop
mkdir /var/tmpfs
echo "none   /var/tmpfs  tmpfs  defaults,size=${RAMDISK_SIZE} 1 2" >> /etc/fstab
mount -t tmpfs -o size=${RAMDISK_SIZE} none /var/tmpfs
cp -R /var/lib/mysql/* /var/tmpfs
mv /var/lib/mysql /var/lib/mysql_old
ln -s /var/tmpfs /var/lib/mysql
chown -R mysql:mysql /var/tmpfs
chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
service mysql start
```

If this does not work, you can reverse it out

```
service mysql stop
rm -f /var/lib/mysql
mv /var/lib/mysql_old /var/lib/mysql
service mysql start
```

You can set the RAMDISK_SIZE to your liking

## OPTION #2 : Use [FUSION IO](http://www.fusionio.com)

Mount `/var/lib/mysql` on a [**FusionIO Disk**](http://www.fusionio.com/products/) (all memory, CPU aggressive).

Have fun clearing this with your CFO.

## EPILOGUE

Both of these options allow you to use MyISAM and InnoDB as you normally would. The goal is simply to place the entire `datdair` in RAM.

## Give it a Try !!!

Comment: FusionIO is much faster than old mechanical disk drives, but it is not RAM.  It uses flash memory, which still has latency in microseconds.  SDRAM has latency on the order of nanoseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Look at MySQL NDBD cluster. It's MySQL database with in-memory storage.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [SQLite](https://sqlite.org/)? It is a widely used, light-weight database which has C/C++ bindings and supports [in memory databases](https://sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html).

Comment: SQLite is lightweight, but it does not have the mysql server, and in my experience there is no performance advantage over mysql.